# WAMP with PHP 5.3.3?

Tags: php, sql, apache, windows-server

http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-07-22-2

I want to test it on Windows but it seems there isn't a fast WAMP server that fits 5.3.3.

Are there any today?

Comment: It means 5.3.3 *onwards* so you can test this in any version that's >= 5.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a 'total amp' package, those would lag somewhat. However, installing the newest version of PHP from http://windows.php.net/download/ yourself should not be a problem, and as long as you have an Apache server running you should be able to make use of the PHP-version you installed.

If you require a package with the preconfigured AMP stack, you'll have to accept those will take some time to incorporate the newest versions of the software, or roll your own.

Comment: I have literally no idea. The last time I used the **W** in WAMP, I just did the work: install Apache, install Mysql, install PHP, and done. Does your favorite WAMP package not have a manual describing how to update one or serveral of it's components? For instance, this on: http://www.wampserver.com/en/faq.php#q1

Answer (score 1):

try http://www.uwamp.com/wiki/UwAmp_main_help

download php from wrikken link then put it on the apache folder.
the one that have

> /ext /extras /PEAR

folder
there should be a 5.3.3 php on options after the new folder is inserted.